# Don't make this hard that it needs to be

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Is this sentence correct ? & would you give me different sentences with the same meaning.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would say:

> Don't make this harder than it needs to be.
>
> Don't make this more difficult than it has to be.
>
> Don't over complicate it.